# Is it wrong if I get training accuracy lower than test accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, data-mining, naive-bayes, weka

I have a dataset with 20000 instances in training, 2300 attributes. I did 10 fold CV and executed on a test set with 9000 instances with naive bayes and J48. The 10 fold CV accuracy is low compared to test accuracy.

Does this mean there's a problem with my data modeling ? How crucial is this result for the classification analysis ?

Answer (score 2):

Since everything is random, in principle there is nothing wrong with that. If the difference is small, don't worry. However, it would be suspicious if you got a much better result on the test set, and maybe there is something weird going on. In that case try splitting your data in a different way (i.e. take a different test set).

Comment: train - 91% , test - 94.6% in J48.. is it fine ?

Comment: It is classification right? In that case, just to be sure, check that the distribution among classes in the response is approximately similar in the training and test sets. If you have more examples of the "easy" classes in your test set, it could make your test estimate of the accuracy too optimistic.

Comment: yes, the class distribution is almost equal for each class. I have 4 classes. each class has approximately 70% of it in train and 30% in test

Comment: Then I wouldn't worry about it too much ^^ These things happen in statistical modeling.